# Free abelian groups question lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Definition:
An abelian group $G$ is free with basis $B$ if $G=\bigoplus_{b\in B}\langle b\rangle$ and each $\langle b \rangle$ is infinite cylic for each $b\in B$.

Lemma:
If $G$ is free with basis $B$ then for each $x\in G$, $x$ has a unique expression $\sum m_bb$ where $m_b\in \mathbb{Z}$  and $m_b=0$ for all but finitely many $b\in B$

My attempt: Let $g\in G$, as $G=\bigoplus_{b\in B}\langle b\rangle$, $g=(g_b)_{b\in B}$, where $g_b=0$ for all but finitely many $b$ and each $g_b=m_bb$ for $m_b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence $g=\sum_{b\in B}(0,.......,m_bb,0......,0)$

However, I am unable to show that $(0........,m_bb,0......,0)=m_bb$.

How does one show this?

Comment: You seem to be conflating external and internal direct sums. The definition you give expresses $G$ as an *internal* direct sum of cyclic subgroups. Your expressions use *external* direct sums. If you are identifying the two, then the equality you want is **by definition**. If you are not identifying the two, then you should not mix them up.

Comment: I don’t really care who you are following. The point is that if you are identifying internal and external direct sums, then there is nothing to show: the two expressions are *identical*, because the left hand side is the external direct sum expression, and the right hand side is the internal direct sum expression. And if you are not identifying them, then you are incorrect from the get go by using external direct sum expressions in an internal direct sum. Doesn’t matter where you got it from, or who you follow or don’t follow.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @ArturoMagidin!

Comment: Are you able to show the lemma is true for $g$s of lengths zero and one?  (The length of $g$ is the number of generators (each appearing with power $-1$ or $1$) used to write $g$.  Note that $g$ *always* has finite length.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin just to be clear, If $G$ is an abelian group and $H,K$ are subgroups. $G$ is the (internal) direct sum of $H$ and $K$ if $H\cap K=0$ and $H+K=G$ and that is equivalent to saying that every member of $g$ may be expressed uniquely as the sum of members in $H$ and $K$?

Comment: Yes; if you have unique expressions, then $G=H+K$, and if $x\in H\cap K$, then $0=0+0=x-x$, so $x=0$. Conversely, if $H\cap K=0$ and $H+K=G$, then the latter tells you every $g\in G$ can be expressed as $h+k$ for some $h\in H$, $k\in K$, and if $h+k=h’+k’$, then $h-h’=k’-k\in H\cap K$, so $h=h’$ and $k=k’$.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin. Your help is always appreciated. Have a beautiful day!